# Error while installing nodejs - could not create shortcut

Tags: node.js, installation

I'm simply trying to install Nodejs on a new hard drive.

I had nodejs previously installed on a hard drive. I then took out the hard drive and put another one in the computer but connected the previous hard drive externally. For sake of simplicity, i'll refer to the new drive as C drive and the external one as D drive. Now i'm trying to install node on the D drive but its giving me an error saying [*Warning 1909. Could not create shortcut nodejs*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Csc4Q.png). After i did some troubleshooting i thought maybe it was due to permissions issues oe something related to that. So i went into my C drive and created the target nodejs folder that the installation would be in and i gave my user profile full control of the folder. I then tried the installation again but it's still giving the same issue.

I also tried running the setup file as administrator. I tried enabling the option using regedit and i also tried using command prompt.